# How to get 3 digit letter of currency and country code based on 2 digit country name in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, internationalization

Is there any package or way to get the 3 digit letter of Currency code and Country code based on 2 digit country name ?

For ex:- If I give two digit country name "us" then I should get currency code as "USD" and country code "USA". Like wise for india if I give country name as "in" then I should get currency code as "INR" and country code "IND".

Well I didn't find any package so far which give Currency and Code based on 2 digit country name

Comment: does [this](https://gist.github.com/HarishChaudhari/4680482) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [country-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/country-data) npm package

Usage

```js
const countryData = require("country-data");

const getCountryCodeAndCurrency = (countryCode) => {
    const country = countryData.countries[countryCode];

    return country
        ? { code: country.alpha3, currency: country.currencies[0] }
        : null;
};

console.log(getCountryCodeAndCurrency('IN')); // {"code":"IND","currency":"INR"}
console.log(getCountryCodeAndCurrency('US')); // {"code":"USA","currency":"USD"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you got a lot of hard work ahead for you. I don't believe there is a premade database, but you can easily implement it with a simple object.

```js
const currencies = {
  "us": { code: "USD", country: "USA" },
  "in": { code: "INR", country: "IND" },
  // ...
}

currencies["in"] // <-- { code: "INR", country: "IND" }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get all data of the country using that reacts library npm install country-list-with-dial-code-and-flag
using this you can get the country name, dial code, flag, and country code
https://www.npmjs.com/package/country-list-with-dial-code-and-flag